# Sort products by attribute filter different select

Tags: sorting, magento, attributes

What i want to do is create a new sort  in the product listing page with an attribute.

Let's say I have and attribute named Color, with the labels Red, Green, Blue. In the product listing page i want to sort products by Color, so if i select Red only products with attribute red should appear.

I have tried everything but nothing works.

What i have in /mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml is the default select, where all attributes are listed like this:

```
 <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                <?php echo $_limit ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Ideas ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting is a way which will just change the order of products but will not eliminate the products from its collection. I believe what you are looking for is a color filter.

What I mean is , if you sort by color red, the products with color red will appear on the top or bottom depending on the order of sort, while remaining products will be below or above it.

While if you consider it as a filter in layered navigation, if you select color red, it will only show red color products while other will be eliminated from list collection.